# how to install laravel on vesta cpanel

Tags: linux, laravel, redhat, vesta

I follow the followlink link for installing laravel on vesta cp.
http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2015/03/25/how-to-host-a-laravel-4-and-5-application-on-a-vestacp-account/
I got the followin errors.Plese solve my issue.

```
Warning: require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/admin/web/2xpzgpbdpqmkpvax.onion/private/app_data/bootstrap/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/2xpzgpbdpqmkpvax.onion/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/2xpzgpbdpqmkpvax.onion/public_html/index.php on line 25
```

Comment: *Warning: require(): `open_basedir` restriction in effect.* seems like permission problem.

Comment: yes sir,can you solve this issue?

Comment: No I don't, just pointing out that it is most likely permission problem, you need to search / google around, contact support etc. Personally I wouldn't follow anything from 2015 (step-by-step guide) tech changes really fast.

Answer (score 1):

upload your project on the following path.

```
/home/admin/web/project_name/public_html/
```

change your config like database name etc.

execute the following commands on server terminal.

```
# Clear Laravel cache and the compiled classes
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled

# Change the storage and cache directories permission
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache

# Regenerate the composer autoload file
composer dump-autoload
```